# Batch file extracting certain tokens from unknown number of delimiters in variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, substring, token, delimiter

Third, and hopefully final revamp of question...

Batch file reading text file with for loop line by line into variable. Each line of said text file can be formatted completely different from the next. The only common delimiter would be a four-digit number (year) somewhere in each line. The goal is to return whatever text follows the aforementioned four-digit number for each line via echo.

Text file example:

```
Monday, January 1, 1900 there was an event-e6718
On this day in 1904 nothing occurred
Wednesday, March 3, 1908 an error occurred when attempting to access the log
Thursday, , 1911 - access denied
Friday, in whatever month, on whatever day, in 1938, nothing happened
```

Therefore, based on the above text file example, the return would be like...

```
there was an event-e6718
nothing occurred
an error occurred when attempting to access the log
- access denied
nothing happened
```

As of 1318 PST, I've tried every code snippet in the comments following, but none of them were able to return the data I need to return.

However, those comments were related to my initial question which has since been markedly improved.

I've even tried a regular expression of "^*[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*$", however I'm new to regex, so I'm sure I have that wrong.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first line, `event=Monday, January 1, 1900 there was an event-e6718` looks as if it may be the output from `set event`, is that correct? How are you defining that variable, `%event%`? I assume that it is part of a bigger command, probably returned within a [tag:for-loop], and probably those are lines parsed from a text file. Can you please provide more of the code in order that we can provide a solution in the appropriate context?

Comment: any particular reason you can't just use substring modification on the known recurring string: `Echo/%event:*there was an event=there was an event%`

Comment: Why don't you share a [mcve] of your attempts?

Comment: Compo: Yes the %event% variable is set via...`set /p event=<"filename.txt"`. T3RR0R: I can't use a specific substring because the text after the year will be different each time. aschipfl: I will upload an example shortly.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63380468/edit) your question and add your code

Comment: If you're taking the first line of a file, then you can use the method @T3RR0R, suggested. **1.** `Set /P "event=" 0< "filename.txt"`, **2.** `Set "event=%event:*there was an event-=There was an event-%"`, and to view it, **3.** `Set event`. You might even get away with: **1.** `Set /P "event=" 0< "filename.txt"`, **2.** `Set "event=%event:*-=There was an event-%"`, and **3.** `Set event`.

Comment: question revamped.

Comment: Will the comma always be there?

Comment: note: the consistency of a variable year number being present in your string is irrlelevant when the string also contains other 4 digit numbers.

Comment: Gerhard, the comma will not necessarily always be there.

Comment: your question should be minimised to "retain the content of a string from the first occurance of a four digit number"

Comment: Updated per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is a horrible task for this. REGEX is a good tool, but `cmd` doesn't support it (with the exception of a very crippled subset with `findstr`). If you are willing to use an [external tool](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), it gets easy:

```
<old.txt call jrepl ".*(\d{4})\D\ *(.*$)" "$2" >new.txt
```

search for a four digit number `\d{4}`, followed by a non-digit `\D` and zero or more spaces, and take the rest until "EndOfLine" `.*$`. (Parentheses) mark matches, referenced by `$x`. Your desired strings are in `$2`.

Output with your example file:

```
there was an event-e6718
nothing occurred
an error occurred when attempting to access the log
- access denied
there was an event-dsfd318
nothing happened
```

Should you decide to include the year, you can find it in `$1`:

```
<old.txt call jrepl ".*(\d{4})\D\ *(.*$)" "$1: $2" >new.txt
```

gives:

```
1900: there was an event-e6718
1904: nothing occurred
1908: an error occurred when attempting to access the log
1911: - access denied
1910: there was an event-dsfd318
1938: nothing happened
```

The `call` is neccessary wihtin a batch file, because `jrepl` is a batch file and therefore wouldn't return without `call`.
(The REGEX pattern might be subject for improvement; I don't have much experience with it yet.)

`jrepl.bat` was programmed by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham).

Answer (score 0):

If there truly is no common point in the string or consistency in token count, adjust the number of iterations in the below for loop to match the maximum possible tokens.

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedexpansion
  Set "event=Monday, January 1, 1900 there was an event-e6718"
  For /L %%i in (1 1 10) Do (
   Set "event=!event:*, =!"
  )& rem // arbitrary number of iterations that should be adjusted to match the maximum expected tokens
  Set "event=%event:~5,100%"& rem // remove the year[space] from the string - final string maximum length is also arbitrary and may need adjusting.
  Echo/%event%
```

** Update **
An example of a macro to get the last token within a for loop using a macro version of the above approach:

Note: you'll need to adjust the file path for yout input file.

```bat
@Echo off

(Set \n=^^^
%=Newline Var=%
)

  Set Gettoken=For %%n in (1 2) Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
    For /F "Delims=" %%G in ("!string!") Do (%\n%
    Set "output=%%G"%\n%
    For %%D in ("!Delim!") Do For /L %%i in (1 1 10) Do Set "output=!output:*%%~D=!"%\n%
    Set "output=!output:~5,100!"%\n%
  )%\n%
  Set output%\n%
) Else Set string=
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "Delim=, "&& For /F "Delims=" %%I in (inputfile.txt) Do %GetToken%%%I
```

## *Edit:*

**single batch solution for the amended questions actual requirement.**

```bat
@Echo off & CD "%~dp0"
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
rem // replace inputfile.txt with your filepath
For /F "Delims=" %%L in (inputfile.txt) Do (
Call :sub "%%L"
rem // the below for loop will remove everything up to including the first year from the string
rem // as well as traling coma[space] / [space]
For %%E in (!Errorlevel!) Do (
 If Not "%%E"=="0" (
  Set "String=!String:*%%E=####!"
  Set "String=!String:####, =!"
  Set "String=!String:#### =!"
  Set "String=!String:####=!"
 )
)
rem // output only if a year "delimiter" was encountered
If not "%%~L"=="!String!" Echo/!String!
)

Exit /b
:sub
Set "String=%~1"
rem // adjust for loop %%I for valid year range and %%# for maximum expected string length
For /L %%I in (1899 1 2050) Do (For /L %%# in (0 1 100) Do (If "!String:~%%#,4!"=="%%I" (Exit /B %%I)))
Exit /B 0
```

Comment: On this one, I only get a bunch of lines of "ECHO is off."

Comment: you've missed something in copying /incorporating it into your code then. update your question with the script you are getting that output from. ensure also that you have command extensions enabled ( a prerequisite for using delayed expansion )

Comment: `@Echo Off  
Cls  
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion  
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Type "C:\TextFile.txt"') Do (  
 Set Event=%%A  
 For /L %%I In (1 1 10) Do Set "Event=!Event:*, =!"  
 Set "Event=%Event:~9,100%"  
 Echo %Event%  
)  
EndLocal  
Exit /B  
`

Comment: you are using the event variable with non delayed expansion within your code block.

Comment: Really? I ensured the "EnableDelayedExpansion" was present prior to the code. How does that not apply to the code that follows?

Comment: `...) Do Set "Event=!Event:*, =!"    Set "Event=%Event:~9,100%"  `
delayed expansion doesn't apply when expanded with `%` expansion, only with `!` expansion

Comment: After correcting the "%" to "!", it returned data this time, but in a fashion I wasn't expecting. It appears to have returned from position 10 through the rest of the line, for the first line. After that, the position in which it starts returning data for the remainder of the lines appears to be random.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "C:\textfile.txt" ^| findstr /IRC:"there was an event"') do (
   set "event=%%i"
   echo "!event:*there was an event=there was an event!"
)
```

**textfile.txt**

```
Monday, January 1, 1900 there was an event-e6718
On this day in 1904 nothing occurred
Wednesday, March 3, 1908 an error occurred when attempting to access the log
Thursday, , 1911 - access denied
Monday, January 1, 1910 there was an event-dsfd318
Friday, in whatever month, on whatever day, in 1938, nothing happened
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works for the first line of text in my OP, other than that, it just echos the entire line.

Comment: Then your other lines have `event` in the text. I added the full string to the `findstr` command. try now.

Comment: Nah...that change only returns the first line. The goal is to return all the data, in every line, following the year (which is always present). So, the consistent data we can key on is the year. Unfortunately, absolutely everything else can change, both before and after the year. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you change anyting in the script? this returns each line that contains `there was an event` is that how your file actually looks like? if not, then you need to change the `findstr` string to mattch what you want. I will include a sample `testfile.txt` in th answer, save it and see the results EXACTLY as the code is now.